# Validating jframe combo box so that the default is not accepted

Tags: java, validation, combobox, jcombobox

I am trying to make sure these combo boxes don't have the default value.

this is my code to validate it so far

```
public boolean checked() {

    /*this code loops through all comboboxes, checks they are not default 
     * and adds 1 to i. if i is 6, by the end of then it means that none
     * are default and true is returned
     */

    int i = 0;

    if(!drop1.equals("Year")){
        i++;    
    }
    if (!drop2.equals("Month")) {
        i++;   
    }
    if (!drop3.equals("Day")) {
        i++;
    }
    if (!drop4.equals("Year Group")) {
        i++;
    }
    if (!drop5.equals("Year")) {
        i++;
    }
    if (!drop6.equals("Year")) {
        i++;
    }

    if (i == 6) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

dropX are the separate drop boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the class methods for jcombobox, I came up with this instead:

```
public boolean checked(){

    /*this code loops through all comboboxes, checks they are not default 
     * and adds 1 to i. if i is 6, by the end of then it means that none
     * are default and true is returned
     */
    int i = 0;
    if(drop1.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        i++;    
    }
    if(drop2.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        i++;   
    }
    if(drop3.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        i++;
    }
    if(drop4.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        i++;
    }
    if(drop5.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        i++;
    }
    if(drop6.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        i++;
    }

    if(i == 6){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

getSelectedIndex() determines the state of the combobox. If the combobox is default (value 0) then I never reach 6.

Comment: What about `drop.getSelectedItem().equals("Year")`?  What [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)?